# Spring How to validate two data member strings have the equal length using @AssertTrue

Tags: java, spring

I have a class containing two String data members:

```
public class Validate 
{
     @NotNull
     private String name1;

     @NotNull
     private String name2;

        // getter and setters for name1 and name2        
}
```

Now I want to have a member method that check if name1 has the same length of name2, and let it fail if they don't have the same length.  So can I do something like this?  I tested it, but it didn't fail anything when lengths are not the same.

```
   public class Validate 
{
     @NotNull
     private String name1;

     @NotNull
     private String name2;

        // getter and setters for name1 and name2       

        @AssertTrue(message = "Length not equal")
        private boolean isEqual()
        {
           return name1.length()== name2.length();
        }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "return name1.length == name2.length;", do:

```
if (name1.length() == name2.length()){
    return true;
} 
return false;
```

It's a bit clearer with an if statement, but the .length**()** bit is the only important bit. I believe that .length on its own works for array sizes, where it refers to an instance variable in the Array object, but it's a method for Strings.

Note: I've never come across those annotations, but I imagine it should still work. On the off chance it doesn't, it's likely a conflict between the "return false;" and the @AssertTrue annotation.

Answer (score 0):

length is not a field of class String. You need to call the method length(). Your confusion probably comes from the fact that the class Array has a publicly-visible field named length, hence, for example

```
int[] ints = new int[]();
ints.length
```

will have the expected output.